# Inserting 1200 records with PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I am working on a project to create a login service for my school. Everything is working so far but I want to be able to transfer all the student info (about 1200 records) from Excel to the database.

It would be the best if I was able to do this from the website but this is not currently working.

I looked through some posts here but was not able to find a fitting solution

```
INSERT INTO leerlingen (Stamnr, Klas, Roepnaam, Tussenv, Achternaam, Adres, Postcode, Woonplaats,Telefoon, Geboortedatum, Binnen, Betaald) VALUES(8101466,'class','name','','name','street','number','city','phone number','bday',0,0);
```

If I use only one insert statement it works all fine but when I try to send 2 or more it doesn't, I don't get an error but it just doesn't do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<script style="tekst/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<title>Zlv pasjessysteem</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.0.css">
</head>
<body onload="screen()">
  <div id="Screen"> <!-- Deze div gaat over het hele scherm-->
    <div id="Menubalk"> <!-- Dit geeft de menubalk aan-->
      <li>
        <ul><a href="Index.php">Home</a></ul>  <!-- Dit geeft de link voor de Home knop aan-->
        <ul><a href="Help.php">Help</a></ul>  <!-- Dit geeft de link voor de Help knop aan-->
        <ul><a href="Instellingen.php">Instellingen</a></ul>  <!-- Dit geeft de link voor de Instellingen knop aan-->
        <ul><a href="Statistiek.php">Statistiek</a></ul>  <!-- Dit geeft de link voor de Statistiek knop aan-->
        <ul><a href="Credits.html">Credits</a></ul>  <!-- Dit geeft de link voor de Credits knop aan-->
      </li>
    </div>
    <div id="tekst">
    <h3>code vanuit je excel bestand voor de nieuwe database</h3>
    <form action="instellingen.php" method="post"><!--maak het form-->
      <textarea name="code"></textarea><br><!--code insert comes here-->
      <input type="submit" value="verstuur"><!--verzend knop-->
    </form>
    <h3>weg met de database</h3>
    <form action="instellingen.php" method="post"><!--maak het form-->
       <input type="submit" value="verwijder database"><!--verzend knop-->
       <input style='display:none;' type=" text" value="remove" name="code"><br><!--remove database-->
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";//connect met de database door middel van deze variabelen
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "zlv";
// begin de verbinding
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());//verbinding mislukt? geef error message
    exit();
}
$code = " ";
if (isset($_POST["code"])){$code=$_POST["code"];
  if($code=="remove"){
    $sql="DELETE FROM leerlingen";
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  }
  else{
  $sql=$code;
  echo $sql;
  $sql="INSERT INTO leerlingen (Stamnr, Klas, Roepnaam, Tussenv, Achternaam, Adres, Postcode, Woonplaats,Telefoon, Geboortedatum, Binnen, Betaald) VALUES(8101466,'value','value','','value','value','value','value','value','1998-04-12',0,0);
INSERT INTO leerlingen (Stamnr, Klas, Roepnaam, Tussenv, Achternaam, Adres, Postcode, Woonplaats,Telefoon, Geboortedatum, Binnen, Betaald) VALUES(8111963,'value','value','','value','value','value','value','value','2003-12-03',0,0)
";
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysql_error());;
  }
}

?>

</body>
```

Note that I put all the multiple query's in one variable (not sure if that is okay). Do I need to do it another way or is there an easier way?

Comment: First of all you're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` only will do a single query. your `$sql` is 2 queries.

Comment: Please, don't add things like *fixed* to your title. You marked the answer as accepted. That will do. Related [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `mysqli_multi_query(...)` instead of `mysqli_query(...)` . Then you are able to execute several queries at once.

Check here: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php

However, you can insert multiple records with one `insert into` statement.

```
INSERT INTO (id, col2, col3)
VALUES (1, val1, val2),
(2, val3, val4),
(3, val5, val6);
```

This would enter three new records.

Check out more here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change the queries to a single query, it won't work with `mysqli_query()`:

```
INSERT INTO leerlingen 
            (stamnr, 
             klas, 
             roepnaam, 
             tussenv, 
             achternaam, 
             adres, 
             postcode, 
             woonplaats, 
             telefoon, 
             geboortedatum, 
             binnen, 
             betaald) 
VALUES      (8101466, 
             'ZH5b', 
             'Sheri', 
             '', 
             'Zwietering', 
             'hacker road 123', 
             '1234 aa', 
             'stad', 
             '075-123456789', 
             '1998-04-12', 
             0, 
             0), 
            (8111963, 
             'ZA1a', 
             'Maaike', 
             '', 
             'lastname', 
             'hacker road 12', 
             '1234 aa', 
             'stad', 
             '075-123456789', 
             '2003-12-03', 
             0, 
             0)
```

If you need multiple queries, use `mysqli_multi_query()` see @blckbird answer